# How to create an AVRO file using Go?

Tags: go, avro

I'm trying to create an AVRO file using Go. So far I tried a couple of libraries and I have some code.

The problem is that I can work with the data but don't know how to serialize it to store it. Here's the code I got from `github.com/hamba/avro` with some small modifications.

```
import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/hamba/avro"
  "log"
)

type SimpleRecord struct {
        A int64  `avro:"a"`
        B string `avro:"b"`
}

func main() {
    schema, err := avro.Parse(`{
        "type": "record",
        "name": "simple",
        "namespace": "hamba",
        "fields" : [
            {"name": "a", "type": "long"},
            {"name": "b", "type": "string"}
        ]
    }`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    in := SimpleRecord{A: 27, B: "foo"}

    data, err := avro.Marshal(schema, in)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

This block of code prints:

```
[54 6 102 111 111]
```

This line corresponds to the avro encoding of the data. And it seems like this is all I need to store, but I don't know how to create the file itself.

I tried:

```
mode := int(0644)
    permissions := os.FileMode(mode)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("file.avro", data, permissions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

And it generates a file. However, when I try to read it as an AVRO file using Python fastavro library, I get the error `ValueError: cannot read header - is it an avro file?`.

But according to the docs (https://godoc.org/github.com/hamba/avro#example-Marshal): "Marshal returns the Avro encoding of v." `Marshal(schema Schema, v interface{}) ([]byte, error)`, so `data` should be of type `[]byte`.

Comment: I know nothing about avro however on their doc page https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html  it says `Data in Avro is always stored with its corresponding schema, meaning we can always read a serialized item, regardless of whether we know the schema ahead of time`  and it references a file xxx.avsc which is the schema file I would say ... so you might want to look into creating the schema file

Answer (score 4):

Avro defines the data encoding format only which can be packaged as messages or files. So, for file storage should use Avro OCF - Avro Object Container Files. Here is a working [hamba avro ocf encoder example](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hamba/avro/ocf?tab=doc#example-NewEncoder).

In my code I've encoded multiple rows to upload it to BigQuery (error checks, init, and close are omitted for clarity):

```
f, err := os.Open("/your/avro/file.avro")
enc, err := ocf.NewEncoder(schema, w, ocf.WithCodec(ocf.Snappy))
for _, item := range items {
    enc.Encode(item)
}
```

Comment: I was struggling for days trying to figure out how to encode multiple rows, mainly I thought I had to use an array. I pray for thanks to the coding gods I stumbled upon this answer. Thanks!